# Python how to read multiple inputs in a same line

Tags: python

I want to know how can we read multiple input like ["a","b","c"] and store it in same variable. I want to store a , b ,c as a separate input to a variable.
thanx

Comment: Like `(a,b,c) = ["a","b","c"]`? It helps if you word your question better or if you actually write it in the form of a question...

Comment: You really need to ask your question more clearly.  I think you're looking for: mylist=sys.stdin.readline().split(',') (if your input is indeed seperated by commas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually getting input from stdin or from a file, then it is as easy as using the split() function

```
f=open( 'myfile.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    # suppose line is '["a","b","c"]'
    a = line.split( ',' )
    # a is now the list [ '["a"', '"b"', '"c"]' ]

    # To strip away the brackets use this instead:
    a = line.strip('[]').split( '[]' )
    # a is now the list [ '"a"', '"b"', '"c"' ]

    # To strip away the spurious quote marks use this instead:
    a = [ s.strip('"') for s in line.strip('[]').split(',') ]
    # a is now the list [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Of course, you could roll this into a single list comprehension:

```
lines = [ s.strip('"') for s in l.strip('[]').split(',') for l in open( 'myfile.txt', 'r' ).readlines() ]
```

I think that should work...I didn't check it in an interpreter.  The idea here is to give you an idea of how you can roll together Pythons very powerful list processing functions with its equally awesome string processing functions.

Remember, read documentation!

Good Luck!

Comment: I love downvotes without comments...

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
a, b, c = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

That assigns three new variables.  If you want to operate on each in turn, use this instead:

```
for character in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
  print character # prints 'a', then 'b', then 'c'.
```

Comment: Ya . I know that but how can I insert the three input to an array. For example: I have >> Input three numbers: 1,2,3. and I want to enter these numbers to the array suppose num [i].

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack iterables:

```
a, b, c = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```